# Translate wkt reference system to proj4 format

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I want to translate this wkt version of the SR-ORG:8399 code reference system, to its corresponding proj4 format, so I can use it in QGIS. The exact characteristics of the system are the following: http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8399/prettywkt/

I have tried to translate to proj4 writing the following format,

```
+proj=longlat +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-170 +k=1.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +units=m +no_defs
```

but QGIS Custom CRS gives a "This projection definition is not valid" message.

Can you help me correct it?

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid you are lost with your task, since `PROJECTION["Rotated_Latitude_Longitude"]` is not implemented in GDAL. In Proj.4, there is a substitute named `+proj=ob_tran`, but it is not imlemented in GDAL (and based on it QGIS as well).

You can follow https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4285 and http://lists.maptools.org/pipermail/proj/2010-June/005234.html on the discussions about that. See also [How to use PROJ4 to reproject a file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89053/how-to-use-proj4-to-reproject-a-file)

Comment: Thank you AndreJ! Could this be resolved in R?

Comment: You might follow https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2012-August/015894.html and https://www.r-bloggers.com/map-projections-in-oce/. Alternativley, there is a python solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760566/plotting-rotated-pole-projection-in-cartopy